# How to match all of a function content in c with regex with least possible overhead

Tags: regex, grep, pattern-matching

Say I would like to match all the content of a function foo() in several file to copy/paste them outside their original file using regex.

For instance, having a function foo() as :

```
(static void) foo(int argc, char* argv[], ...)  
            {
              {...
                {...
                }
              }
            }
```

I would like to match all the function passing only the name "foo". I have tried something like this as a positive lookBehind but it didn't work well:

```
grep -Po '*foo(?<=\{).*(?=\})' test.c
```

any ideas will be appreciated. 
As a workaround, I was looking to find a way to count all the opened parentheses and match them till the last renaming closing parentheses, i suppose.

P.S: In the latest case, I would appreciate any thought on implementing a c/c++ code for that.

Comment: Regex is not defined for this (C functions aren't remotely close to a regular language). Best bet is to use a dedicated parser.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, by dedicating parser you mean i write one in scratch? If so, I don't think that would be a good idea cuz I am interested in puting this script inside a loop for thousand of times. therefore, less overhead the better

Comment: @Amir 1- Please don't shout in your post 2- It's better to use a dedicated parser, you don't need to write it from scratch, there should already be at least one around 3- If you really want to use regex, you'll need to use a regex engine that supports recursion like PCRE or balancing groups like .NET. But even then, the regex will be extremely complicated if you want to account for comments `/* Random } */`, basic string `"random }"` and much more. Anyways, here's a [recursive regex](http://regex101.com/r/dM0lI8/1), see how it fails in the second and third examples. TLDR: lolwut

Comment: "... count ... match brackets ..."  Regex won't do this.  And you have to worry about brackets found in strings, comments, and dead blocks of preprocessor-conditioned code.   Frankly, you need a full C parser to handle all this stuff.

Comment: @IraBaxter sounds bad :(

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using grep I'll assume you are on some type of *nix box. There is a tool called **ctags** that you can learn about [here](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) . It is useful for parsing source files for things like variables, function, etc. It may help with your situation here.

Comment: Tnx for the suggestion, but I would prefer to use built-in bash script with less overhead

Comment: Finding a bash only solution will likely create more overhead than a bash + external c parser solution. If your bash script is calling grep then you already have overhead since grep is an external command like ctags is. ctags can deal with a large number of files easily.

Answer (score 1):

What OP needs is a pattern matching system that operates on program structures.  You can find these in the category of [Program Transformation Systems (PTS)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_transformation) .

PTS usually offer a pattern language that matches against parse trees using a language-accurate grammar, applied to the code of interest, using the vocabulary from the grammar.   It can thus handle arbitrary nesting of constructs (this is where regex falls flat on its face).

Our PTS, the DMS Software Reengineering Toolkit, would express OP's pattern as:

```
 pattern  match_type-returning_function(type_declaration T, IDENTIFIER: name, arguments:A, block_body: B):function =
      " \T \name ( \A ) { \B } "
```

The pattern values T, name, A, and B will match against language constructs  type_declaration, IDENTIFIER, arguments, and block_body respectively, and will be bound to the sub-trees they cover.  The pattern is written in the surface syntax of the target language, in this case C, embedded in *meta* quotes "...", with pattern variables marked as  \patternvar.  Because the matching is against trees, the actual formatting of the text is irrelevant.

You might need an additional pattern for void results, since void isn't a type_declaration:

```
 pattern  match_void_function(IDENTIFIER: name, arguments:A, block_body:B):function =
      " void name ( \A ) { \B }"
```

With a PTS, after a pattern has been matched, one can apply operations on the matched part of the pattern, either to report a result, or carry out transformations.

These patterns aren't very complicated compared to what people usually write.  A more interesting pattern might be, "find a function that contains an auto-increment operator as a statement".

One might write that as:

```
  pattern  match_type-returning_function(type_declaration T, IDENTIFIER: name, arguments:A, block_body: B):function =
      " \T \name ( \A ) { \B } if  :>(B,auto_increment)
```

where auto-increment is defined as:

```
   pattern auto_increment(L_value: L):statement =
        " L++; "
```

and the (admittedly arcane) syntax ":>(x,y)" means "match pattern y to the tree x" and return boolean true if a match is found, false if not".  The net effect in this rule is that after a function has been found, the body is pattern-searched for an autoincrement.

Match tree-patterns to trees is generally pretty efficient.

Other PTS express similar patterns with different arcane syntax, but usually the ideas are the same.   (However, to our knowledge, of all the PTS available, only DMS has a full, robust C and C++ parsers; and you'll still have to run a preprocessor [DMS has one] to make sure the full syntax of the functions are visible to the parser).